# "No module named xpopup.file" error when try to run kivy designer

Tags: python, kivy

When i try to run "python -m designer" command i get this error:

```
   File "designer/app.py", line 14, in <module>
     from designer.components.dialogs.add_file import AddFileDialog
   File "designer/components/dialogs/add_file.py", line 5, in <module>
     from kivy.garden.xpopup.file import XFileOpen, XFolder
 ImportError: No module named xpopup.file
```

i think the module isn't at the right place. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How did you install kivy.garden.xpopup? Although just so you know, the designer doesn't work well and is not actively maintained, even if you get it running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed Kivy Designer on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Windows 10. I have problem running Kivy Designer on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it always crash. But I have no problem running in on Windows 10 64-bits using Python 3.6.2. You have to do the following:

To install the XPopup enter a console (on Windows use kivy.bat in the kivy folder):

```
garden install xpopup
```

Comment: It solved my problem. Now I can use the designer. Thank you!